# How to create unstructured 2D meshes from CAD files in python

Tags: python, 2d, mesh, cad

I'm working on a finite differences code to solve 2D problems. I want to be able to solve complex geometries written as STEP or IGES files. However I don't know how to read and mesh this kind of files.

While I know that there are free and independent meshing applications, I want my code to be self-contained. Is there a way to achieve this on python?

Comment: What do you mean by self-contained? Is using an external library counts as "self-contained"? Or you are looking more on the lines of "I don't want to use another executable"?

Comment: More on the lines that I dont want to use another executable. Using libraries is ok.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in [GMSH API](http://gmsh.info/doc/texinfo/gmsh.html#Gmsh-API). GMSH is well-known for a while as a free open-source mesher, and recently (by relative means), they introduced an API for C,C++, Python, and Julia.

At first, a simple usage of [Top level functions](http://gmsh.info/doc/texinfo/gmsh.html#Namespace-gmsh) `GMSH::open` and [Mesh function](http://gmsh.info/doc/texinfo/gmsh.html#Namespace-gmsh_002fmodel_002fmesh) `GMSH::generate(2)` can get you started.